How to return pathname-name in a dolist loop?
I am trying to fill a hash-table with lists of pathnames derived from a directory structure. The structure looks like this:
├── audio
│   ├── aliinaMay23 -> /home/kf/mySamples/aliinaMay23
│   ├── alla -> /home/kf/mySamples/UpSitDown/alla
│   ├── aluminumBangs -> /home/kf/mySamples/aluminumBangs
│   ├── bd -> /home/kf/mySamples/bd/
│   ├── beachWaveLoop -> /home/kf/mySamples/beachWaveLoop
│   ├── blowBubbles -> /home/kf/mySamples/blowBubbles
│   ├── bodyPerc -> /home/kf/mySamples/bodyPerc
... etc

If I try to print out a single dir-name, it works, but when I loop over the list of the directories, then I only get nil. What am I missing here?
(print (pathname-name "audio/bd")) ; prints out "bd", as expected

(dolist (dir (uiop:subdirectories "audio"))
  (print (pathname dir))) ; prints out the pathnames of the subfolders, as expected

(dolist (dir (uiop:subdirectories "audio"))
  (print (pathname-name dir))) ; prints out one nil per subfolder. Why?


My guess is that subdirectories returns names with just a directory portion, not filenames, like audio/aliinaMay23/

Try (pathname-directory dir)

See the CL Cookbook

Do those arrows mean everything in the audio directory is a symlink?

And your title is about returning names but your code prints stuff and doesn't return anything (besides dolist's default single nil, of course)

@Barmar: (pathname-directory dir) gives me a bunch of (:ABSOLUTE "home" "kf" ".local" "share" "SuperCollider" "Extensions"  "Ouroboros" "audio" "xyloNoise")  (:ABSOLUTE "home" "kf" ".local" "share" "SuperCollider" "Extensions"  "Ouroboros" "audio" "xylophoneStretch")   etc..., which is not quite what I'm looking for.

@Shawn, yes indeed... Couldn't find a way to edit the title...

Note that "audio/bd" is probably not the name of a directory in your Lisp. "audio/bd/" might be a name of a directory in your Lisp.

note that instead of print you can call describe with the whole dir object to see their components: you have a nil name probably with the full component. Maybe you need to store the whole pathname in your hash table, or the namestring?

Ah, this works:
(dolist (dir (uiop:subdirectories "audio"))   
  (print (first (last (pathname-directory dir)))))

